# k(k-1)/2: Combinations and the Birthday bound

Tags: encryption, birthday-attack

Disclaimer: I'm new to cryptography.

Background: I'm reading Cryptography Engineering by Ferguson, Schneier, and Kohno, where, in Chapter 2, the authors write this:

[image]

Question: What is $k(k-1)/2$ called? It seems related to an arithmetic sequence $a_n = a_1 + (n-1)d$ and some kind of combination (my notes below), but I can't place it.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number ​ ​

Comment: It's the number of pairs. It's your lower right formula if you fix $r=2$.

Comment: @SEJPM Just nitpicking: "pairs" is quite ambiguous in this context (it could mean any of the above except the lower left). I would use the term *two-element subsets*.

Answer (score 2):

$k(k-1)/2$ is usually called a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and written $k \choose 2$. It corresponds to the number of unordered pairs of distinct elements out of $k$ elements. It does indeed correspond to the sum ${k \choose 2} = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} i$. This is quite intuitive: fixing one element, you have $k-1$ pairs containing this element. Now remove it, consider a second element: you have $k-2$ pairs with this second element, and so on. At the end, you get $(k-1) + (k-2) + \cdots +2 + 1 = k(k-1)/2$ pairs.

your bottom right formula is the general formula for ${k \choose r}$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have picked $k$ elements $e_1, e_2, .., e_k$ and you want to check if two of them have the same property (the same birthday, for instance).

Then, you can fix $e_1$ and compare it with all the other elements. This give you $k-1$ sets:

$\{e_1, e_2\},\{e_1, e_3\},\{e_1, e_4\},...,\{e_1, e_k\}$

And you can fix $e_2$ and check the property for all the other elements except $e_1$, because you already checked it ($\{e_1, e_2\} = \{e_2, e_1\}$). So you get the following $k-2$ sets:

$\{e_2, e_3\},\{e_2, e_4\},\{e_2, e_5\},...,\{e_2, e_k\}$

In the same way, the element $e_3$ gives you $k - 3$ sets

$\{e_3, e_4\},\{e_3, e_5\},\{e_3, e_6\},...,\{e_3, e_k\}$

the element $e_{k-1}$ gives you only the set $\{e_{k-1}, e_k\}$ and the element $e_k$ gives you nothing.

So, the total number of sets is

$$(k-1) + (k-2) + (k-3) + ... + 2 + 1$$

and this quantity is equal to $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$.